# How to increase the width of custom filter list in ag-grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

How to increase the width of custom filter list in ag-grid?

```
filterParams: {
          newRowsAction: 'keep',
          suppressMiniFilter: true,
          **filterWidth: 500,**
          values: function(params) {
            setTimeout(function() {
              params.success([
             // code  
               ]),
}
```

Comment: I am not able to set width size of the filter list drop down in custom filter. If my custom filter cell has characters exceeding the width of the setfilter then it the rest of the characters disappears. Need to set my own width. If someone can help me then it will be great! Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to use ng-deep in your CSS file to manipulate filter container styles:

```
:host ::ng-deep .ag-filter-body-wrapper 
{
    width: 600px;
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you!! It worked!! I am so happy and grateful for the solution.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. @RubeenaBegum

Comment: @behruz thanks for solution but effect will happen with every colDef. How to set width in specific column filed . ?